# Priority order of attack of grignard reagents on functional groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, reactivity, grignard-reagent

[image]

Recently I was solving carbonyl compounds and I came across this. Is there some *priority order*, or logic behind why alcohol reacts first with Grignard reagent and then ketone. Whereas ester could've reacted with *2 moles of RMgX* but didn't.

Comment: What is the difference between Grignard reagent reacts with either $\ce{R-OH}$ or $\ce{R-CO-R'}$? There is a pretty good reason for that.

Comment: so  the first one seems like a base so acid-base reaction? And the second one will undergo nucleophilic addition ? so acid-base before substitution . is that it?(●'◡'●)

Comment: Looks good but is the structure of R shown?

Comment: @shreya: You are correct, when acidic hydrogen is present it react first such as tin the case of given 1st reaction to give $a$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the compound given in the question, the priority order of Grignard reagent attack follows,

$\ce{R-OH > R-CO-R' > R-COOR'}$

**Reason:**

- Acid-base neutralisation are very fast.
- Carbonyl carbon is more nucleophilic than carboxylic carbon, as the latter one is stabilized by resonance.

---

Therefore, first alcohol is attacked and hence **P** is **(a)**, then the carbonyl part is attacked and hence **Q** is **(b)**.

Finally, one more mole of RMgX gets used up on the carboxyl part, hence **R** is **not (d)**.